# Test Dropbox webhooks implementation with self-signed certificate?

Tags: dropbox-api, webhooks

I'm setting up use of Dropbox webhooks in a web application. I'd like to do the development on my local machine. I can access my local machine via https from the Internet, but when I try to add the URL as a webhook URI in Dropbox App Console I found that it seems to require the SSL certificate to not be self-signed. Is there a way to do testing on a local machine with a self-signed certificate? The error message is below. After complaining about the cert it also says there is no response body, but I'm guessing this is because it didn't even get as far as checking the body (I've tested my URL by loading it directly in a browser and via wget from a remote server and the response contains the desired content).

> Error: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
>
> Request: GET
>   https://my.domain.com/dropbox-webhook?challenge=urFYi8g-jCkVM7aP676BAyYlH7Z3u04RAJH5Lu0AYLg
>
> Response:(No headers)
>
> Response Body (First 256 bytes):(No response body)

Comment: [Cross-linking with Dropbox API forum post: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/communities/public/questions/201371679-Test-webhooks-implementation-with-self-signed-certificate- ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For local development, I leaned on https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox_hook pretty hard to test everything. It's what I would recommend for local development of dropbox webhooks.